# UTF-16BE and UTF-16 issue in java

Tags: java, character-encoding, utf-16

I have a file, when displayed with *geanny* * shows *UTF-16BE*. If I try to convert this file in *Java* to a different encoding (let's say *ISO-8859-1*), assuming it is *UTF-16BE*, a question mark (?) appears every time at the beginning of new created file. If instead I assume it is in *UTF-16* (something that's not true), the converted file gets converted ok, without any question mark at the beginning.
Can anybody clarify why this behavior?

Bellow is a snippet from my used code:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, utf16beCharset));
    String line = null;

    while ( (line = buff.readLine()) != null) {

        sb.append(line);
        sb.append('\n');
    }

    String output = new String(sb.toString().getBytes(neededCharset), neededCharset);
    System.out.println(output);
```

* *geanny* is a text editor

Comment: Must be the BOM, which isn't expected in BE mode (you already know it's BE then, right?).

Comment: @Bram If this isn't expected in BE, why does it appear?

Comment: @artaxerxe The BOM is not part of the UTF-16BE encoding, thats why it displays a questionmark.

Comment: @WonderWorld: A `?` appears if the BOM itself is converted to a non-UTF charset instead of being stripped off prior to converting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Problem is the BOM ([Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)).

If you define the character set as `UTF-16` then Java recognises the BOM and removes it after reading. The BOM then tells Java that the character stream is (UTF-16)BE.

If you define `UTF-16BE` then you tell Java to ignore the BOM and Java ignores it and writes it to your target file.

Comment: how to detect & ignore such characters?

Comment: @DivyangShah The BOM is 0xFEFF (as described in the linked article). So either let Java do the detection and removal or remote the first 2 bytes in an UTF-16 stream.